# How to Resolve Possible Cut and Paste Error.?

Tags: android, android-layout

Error with reference id in Android Studio.
It shows that the id has already been looked up in this method.
I have given the id name same as used in the code but it does not work. 
I have already tried chaining the id and reusing it but it shows the same error.
Please need some help. The error message image is in the hyper link.

[image: error message]

**This is my code**

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnSignup;
    TextView btnLogin,btnForgotPass;
    EditText input_email,input_pass;
    RelativeLayout activity_sign_up;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    Snackbar snackbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        //View
        btnSignup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signup_btn_register);
        btnLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.signup_btn_login);
        btnForgotPass = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.signup_btn_forgot_pass);
        input_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
        input_pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
        activity_sign_up = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_sign_up);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to clean project and rebuild or try to invalidate cache and restart...

Comment: and make sure `activity_sign_up.xml` contains all the id you want

Comment: thank u guys.. that really worked  :) @santanu sur

Comment: how to do that? @ santanu sur

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to **Build - > Rebuild Project** if this doesnot work... go to **File -> Invalidate cache/Restart...**